# Automated tests on TFS 2010 using a test assembly file specification

Tags: unit-testing

I'm using TFS, it works fine. Now I want to add tests and code coverage. So I create a Local.testsettings. Running tests on my computer runs fine.

Configuration of the TFS Build is as follows:
- Automated test with test assembly file specification and the same test settings file (as recommended, instead of using a .vsmdi file)

When launching a build with TFS, my tests don't get executed :

Run MSTest for Test Assemblies
The MSTestActivity was invoked without a value for Platform or Flavor. The values Mixed Platforms and Debug were used.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe /nologo /usestderr /testSettings:"C:\Builds\1\MyProject\Sources\MyProject\Main\Source\MyProject\Local.testsettings" /searchpathroot:"C:\Builds\1\MyProject\Binaries" /resultsfileroot:"C:\Builds\1\MyProject\TestResults" /testcontainer:"C:\Builds\1\MyProject\Binaries\MyProject.Tests.Module1.dll" /maxpriority:"1" /minpriority:"1" /publish:"http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/Test" /publishbuild:"vstfs:///Build/Build/433" /teamproject:"MyProject" /platform:"Mixed Platforms" /flavor:"Debug" 
Loading C:\Builds\1\MyProject\Sources\MyProject\Main\Source\MyProject\Local.testsettings...
Loading C:\Builds\1\MyProject\Binaries\MyProject.Tests.Module1.dll...
Starting execution...
No tests to execute.
There are no results to be published.

So it finds the assembly, but MSTest doesn't actually runs the tests.
Any hint is welcome.

Comment: What type of test is it?

Comment: A simple unit test using Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at this:

```
 /maxpriority:"1" /minpriority:"1"
```

It looks like your priority criteria may be the problem.

Comment: I set maxpriority = 2 and minpriority = 1, it doesn't have any impact.

Comment: Try setting maxpriority to maxint (should be the default), or just clear both fields in the build definition's process parameter.